# i get error after simple try to store json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

In python 3,3

```
import  json

peinaw = {"hi":4,"pordi":6}
json_data = open('data.json')
json.dump(peinaw, json_data)
json_data.close()
```

i get

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
fp.write(chunk)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

tried same thing in 2,7 and it works.I s there a different way in 3,3?

Comment: You have to enable the `write`-flag in `json_data = open('data.json')` with the parameter `'w'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import  json
>>> peinaw = {"hi":4,"pordi":6}
>>> with open('data.json', 'w') as json_data: # 'w' to open for writing
        json.dump(peinaw, json_data)
```

I used a `with` statement here, where the file is automatically `.close()`d at the end of the `with` block.

Answer (score 2):

You are not opening the file for writing. The file is opened in a `read` mode. to verify do this:

```
json_data = open('data.json')
print (json_data) # should work with 2.x and 3.x
```

To solve the probem, just open the file in `write` mode.

```
json_data = open('data.json', 'w')
```

Also, you should use the `with` statement when woking with files.

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as json_data:
   json.dump(peinaw, json_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open file for writing, use 'w' mode parameter:

```
json_data = open('data.json', 'w')
```